# how to mock laravel eloquent model

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, mocking, laravel-4, phpunit

I keep fumbling over this - how do I mock a model that extends form `Eloquent` in Laravel 4 for my unit test?

I keep getting the following error w/ my current way

`ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object`

**Example**

```
use \Repository\Text\EloquentText;
use \Faker\Factory as Faker;

class EloquentTextTest extends TestCase {

public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    $stub = $this->getMock('Text');
    $stub->expects($this->any())->method('save');

    $this->_fixture = new EloquentText($stub);
}

/**
 * @test
 */
public function createShouldCreateNewTextEntry()
{
    $faker = Faker::Create();
    $data = [
        'title' => $faker->sentence,
        'content' => $faker->text,
        'level_id' => $faker->randomDigit,
        'is_public' => $faker->numberBetween(0, 1),
        'is_visible' => $faker->numberBetween(0, 1),
    ];

    $text = $this->_fixture->create($data);

    $this->assertEquals($data['title'], $text->title);
    $this->assertEquals($data['content'], $text->content);
    $this->assertEquals($data['level_id'], $text->level_id);
    $this->assertEquals($data['is_public'], $text->is_public);
    $this->assertEquals($data['is_visible'], $text->is_visible);

    return $text;
}
```

Comment: What are you testing exactly? If you want to see if content is truly saved, you might want to not mock Eloquent at all (might want to use a different DB adapter, such as in-memory sqlite to test). If you mock Eloquent, then you might effectively only test that you called that method, which isn't a useful test. 100% code coverage isn't always worth it :D